# Can IntelliJ hide Java boilerplate code, e.g. getters and setters

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Is it possible in IntelliJ (via a plugin or in any other way) that instead of this Java code:

```
public class Data {
  private int intField1;
  private int intField2;

  public int getIntField1() { return intField1; }
  public void setIntField1(int intField1) { this.intField1 = intField1; }
  public int getIntField2() { return intField2; }
  public void setIntField2(int intField2) { this.intField2 = intField2; }
}
```

It only shows this:

```
public class Data {
  private int intField1; // read-write
  private int intField2; // read-write

  /*boilerplate*/
}
```

To detail the intentions:

- The comments at the right of the fields should be marked as automatically generated (light green background).
- All the boilerplate code should be folded in a single block. Currently, each of the methods is already folded, but their code is still uninteresting, as it is automatically generated.
- When some methods don't follow the expected format, they should not be folded into the boilerplate block.

Comment: Why limit to IntelliJ? Hide all your boilerplate code everywhere using [project lombok](https://projectlombok.org/features/Data.html)

Answer (score 2):

I think the best you can do is custom code folding, explained here:

https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2012/03/custom-code-folding-regions-in-intellij-idea-111/

I don't think it's possible to hide it as a comment as you have suggested, but that would be nice.. perhaps raise a request.

Comment: Exactly what I was thinking :)